# Is there any way to get the number of downloads of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have been doing R&d for some time and I am trying to make a single platform where I can see all the numbers of downloads of my iOS app. I have gone through the [documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/itc14b94d665) but the way we can see the app statistics is through login and then download the report. I like to do it pro-grammatically without using any third party extensions or packages. Just like for android you can use google storage api here in the docs [google cloud storage (API)](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export). But is there any way to do the same with iOS apps ? The only API which they have exposed is [App store connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi) but it gives you results of sales and trends. I am not sure if it tells you also the number of downloads of your app.

Please point me in the right direction. I might be following the wrong path but I have googled a lot and i could not find a direct way to do that without using third party extensions.

Comment: Publisher focused App store related questions is off-topic. Understand why you are asking for downloads: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/measuring-app-performance/ and https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev183adc0b6

Comment: @MorrisonChang you did not get my point I want to get no of downloads of my app without using login. In simple words on my web app, i want to see how many downloads my app has ?

Comment: Unclear how you can get data without authorization. Even with Google command line tool you need to authorize: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export same for Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests Once you get data put it in your web app/custom report generator.

Comment: @MorrisonChang again you misunderstood, i meant to say without login manually. ofcourse one will authenticate and authorize to see that data.

Comment: Okay so either you are asking about the contents of the data (download sales report) or access which I've covered in the prior comments. You are going to need a server (like node.js) to do the work which is how I interpret the words "without login manually". If you are asking if it can be done as a HTML/JavaScirpt/CSS page only - I doubt it. Otherwise to me the ask is unclear. Perhaps you should explain what you mean by "third party extensions".

Comment: @MorrisonChang I want to display no of installs / downloads of my app using any API or xyz method on my web dashboard without using third party tools like https://appfigures.com/. I hope you understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216149/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-usman-i).

Comment: @UsmanI did u got any solution?

Comment: @RamprasathSelvam unfortunately No.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation for the App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports), the endpoint `GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports` gives you daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly app sales figures. That's not *downloads* exactly, since somebody might download your app multiple times in order to install it on multiple devices, reinstall it after deleting it, etc. But it's probably the closest you're going to get without either creating your own analytics system or using a 3rd party one.

Comment: so you are saying through sales i have to figure out my no of downloads ?

Comment: Hi is there any way to get no. of downloads from App Store now? especially for free app.